# Автозагрузка в Win XP

Tags: python, windows

Здравствуйте, если кто знает, можете подсказать, как прописать выполнение скомпилированного python скрипта в exe файл, для автоматического его запуска вместе со стартом системы? Интересны решения под Win XP.

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, делается это просто:

```
#нужный для этого функционал находится в _winreg (в python3 он называется winreg)
from _winreg import *

#открываем нужную ветку
#HKEY_CURRENT_USER - текущий пользователь
#HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - глобально, для всех
mykey = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run')

#пишем наш ключ
#если не хватит прав, то будет исключение WindowsError: [Error 5]
SetValueEx(mykey, 'ИМЯ_КЛЮЧА', 0, REG_SZ, 'C:\ПУТЬ_И_ИМЯ\ВАШЕГО\ФАЙЛА.exe')

#можно закрыть ветку, но это не обязательно
CloseKey(mykey)
```

более подробно
[docs.python.org/library/_winreg](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в реестре в ключ

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

путь к вашему исполняемому файлу.

[Описание разделов реестра Run, RunOnce, RunServices, RunServicesOnce и Startup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365).

Comment: Спасибо, вот мне как раз было интересно как реализовать добавление записи в реестр прогрмно, руками то понятно что я могу добавить, а вот как програмного - это я не пойму.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [Автозапуск программы при включении компютера C++](http://hashcode.ru/questions/31679/). А проще всего создать файл реестра и импортировать его утилитой regedit.exe.

    REGEDIT.EXE [ /L:system | /R:user ] [ /S ] importfile.REG